# Is there any way to get Facebook read_stream permission using the latest Fb?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am developing Social networking iPhone app in which we have facebook as one of the option. We have to display user's feeds but for that I need read_stream permission.

Unfortunately, our app has not been verified. This is message that we’ve received from the Facebook review team:

This permission is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook client on platforms that don’t have a native client. It may only be used to provide people with access to this content.

I am not getting what exactly I have to do to acquire this permission. Is there anyone who has solved the above issue?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0 . It say: "This permission is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook client on platforms that don’t have a native client" which mean that if you are making an ios app you will not be granted that permission

Comment: Then how [Hootsuite](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/hootsuite-for-twitter-facebook/id341249709?mt=8) use it?

Comment: They have an app that was active before 4/30/2014 so they have until 4/30/2015 to upgrade to API v2.0 and get approved

Comment: Mine was rejected too yesterday, for Android app. Is that means this permission can only be requested on device without native facebook app, like washing machine/vacuum cleaner? Because most mainstream devices already has Facebook native app.

Comment: @VHanded
the sad thing I bet now there are a lot of developers that wasting tons of hours on ios /android app that get facebook data, and did not notice this info in docs. facebook need to display this in the main page of graph api.

Answer (score 0):

GO to https://developers.facebook.com and there is an option for Tools-->GraphExplorer-->Graph API Explorer --> select your app click Get Access Token --> select the user data permissions and extended permissions --> Get access token . After that go to Apps--> select your application--> Status and Review --> in this you want to  Add Notes --> and provide the version and upload the screen shots and submit for Review. Hope this may will help you..

Comment: What you are explaining here ? there is other way to get permissions? and facebook review team will consider access token i created in Graph API Explorer ?

Comment: Now facebook api is updated ... you need to chage according to the apiversion

Comment: I am using facebook graph api v2 , here check my question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234830/facebook-read-stream-issue-graph-api  .

And i didnt get you answer -  Tools-->GraphExplorer-->Graph API Explorer --> select your app click Get Access Token etc.... why all this  ????