# How can I get posts on my wall by another user via the Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My goal was to get every from my wall post and process the posts.

When making a request, I would get back a response missing a newer message that was posted by another user.

This is seen in `/user/feed` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed), which is described as:

> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this person, or by others on this person's profile.

Answer (score 0):

There are several cases that stop this from happening, one of them somewhat hidden in the docs and the other un-mentioned.

To have something appear:

1. **both** users must have authenticated with your app.
2. the sharing user must not have hidden status messages from apps in their privacy settings.

The first one is less intuitive, but it requires that the user who is authenticated both have the ability to see it if they were on the site, but that the originating user must also have authenticated with your app.

The second one makes sense, but is unmentioned and can be a frustration if you forget turning that setting on years prior.

Comment: one important thing to mention is that read_stream will only get approved for apps on platforms without a native facebook experience (like TVs).

Comment: Interesting.  I couldn't find that in the docs officially.  Is there somewhere you came across that?

Comment: for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378997/is-there-any-way-to-get-facebook-read-stream-permission-using-the-latest-fb

Comment: or in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1 (see read_stream)