# Facebook read_stream issue graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created facebook app for my website & To enriches the user's experience i need extended permissions from facebook for my app ( which includes read_stream with some other permission ) , i have submitted the app for reviews with valid description but submission were not approved and i could not find any valid reason for that.

I noticed this description in read_stream --  Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.  , can you please explain meaning of this ?

Here is my reference site - https://hootsuite.com/  , they are using read_stream as well.

Answer (score 5):

Hootsuite is using a v1.0 App created before v2.0 was introduced. It will stop working for them after April 2015, when they have to go through the review process too. You will not get `read_stream` approved for your website, as you can read in the quote you posted.

Meaning, you can only use `read_stream` in an App created before end of April 2014, and only until end of April 2015. Not worth using it anymore imho.

Comment: Are you sure  ?  :(   , i added ticket on facebook as well for confirmation. If they cant provide the read_stream permission then why this is in extended_permissions list ?

Comment: @luschn is right. It's in the list of permissions because it clearly exists, and the docs clearly state the use cases for this permission.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

So, I strongly doubt that you'll receive this permission during app review.

Answer (score 1):

Now someone can use "**user_posts**" permission - This new permission allows an app to access the posts on a person's Timeline. This includes the someone's own posts, posts they are tagged in and posts other people make on their Timeline. 
This is a useful alternative to News Feeds.
Previously, this content was accessible with the read_stream permission. The user_posts permission is automatically granted to anyone who previously had read_stream permission.

[Facebook Platform Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_new_features)

Comment: read_stream is different from user_posts ,  read_stream gives you your complete wall but user_posts gives your own posts, posts they are tagged in and posts other people make on their Timeline.
You can clearly see the difference in wall and timeline.